# vertical-dropdown-css

Tags: css

what I need to look for is to only show the top level pages, unless a top level page is clicked on, then I want it to show the sub pages that go under just that one top level page that was clicked.i want that to be done in css. when parent page is clicked then i want the drop down menu to be shown.am doing it in vertical menus.i want it to be shown like this way:

Parent #1

Parent #2

Parent #3

Parent #4

when parent 1 is just clicked it should go like this:

Parent #1

- Child #1a
- Child #1b

Parent #2

Parent #3

Parent #4

Answer (score 1):

Have look to this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY2EN/4/) . I think this will help you.

What you need to do is to use jQuery horizontal accordion menu.

Comment: these are my pages  <div id="menu">

 <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'secondry-nav', 'fallback_cb' => 'com_navigation()', 'container' => 

'',)); ?>
   
</div>

Comment: you are using WP, Ops! i have the same issue have look it http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40869/how-to-remove-div-container-in-custom-menu

Comment: orite n is this any way to send u a personal message??actually am having a long description wanna make you understand that.that would be cery kind of you if you can guide.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your case you need to add menu class (i.e `menu`).

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu_class' => 'menu',
    'theme_location' => 'secondry-nav',
    'container' => ''
) );
```

and make changes in your css to apply styling to the class selector rather than the id selector (change `#menu` to `.menu`)

Comment: hello i have tried that..nothing happening..do check your mail.thank you!